# How to create a paragraph based on user input Android Studio

Tags: android, python

I am wanting to create a script based on user input
I want the android app to ask the user What is your  name? what is ID number? and so on. After a couple questions it will create a paragraph based on the answers.

I have a python script I am working on . is it possible to call the python script on an android app?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options for running python scripts on android:

Kivy: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android

QPython: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpyplus&hl=en

SL4A: https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a